# How to show current data from array to boostrap modal in vue.js

Tags: arrays, vue.js, modal-dialog

--Question--

--Question--

Hi, I'm a noob programmer who is trying to build a Vue web app. I have a problem where I have an array with json data that I loop through and pass to a component, but in that component, I have a bootstrap modal that I wanna show the current data.

It works but when I click the modal it only shows the first obj in the array (0) so it doesn't continue? Can someone please help me with this problem? I hope you guys understand my question, thanks.

---Page CODE (Parent)---

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-xl-0"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-xl-12">
          <h1 id="TreePageTitle"> Text here </h1>
          <div id="grid">

            <TreeCard
              data-toggle="modal"
              data-target="#exampleModalScrollable"
              v-for="tree in treeArray"
              :key="tree.id"
              :tree="tree"
            />

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-xl-0"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TreeCard from "../components/TreeCard.vue";
export default {
  name: "Trees",
  components: {
    TreeCard
  },

  data() {
    return {
      treeArray: [],
      errors: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    try {
      this.treeArray = [
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "obj name 1",
          image:
            "image url here",
          description: "test 1"
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "obj name 2",
          image:
            "image url here",
          description: "test 2"
        }

      ];
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

---Component CODE (Child)---

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="card" v-on:click="toggle">
      <img :src="tree.image" class="img-fluid" id="CardImg" />
      <h2 class="card-title">{{tree.name}}</h2>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div
        class="modal fade"
        id="exampleModalScrollable"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">{{tree.name}}</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              {{tree.description}}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"> Close </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Card",
  data() {
    return {
      bodyID: {}
    };
  },
  props: {
    tree: {}
  },
  methods: {
     toggle: function() {
      this.bodyID = this.tree.id;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure the element id's are unique, as jQuery uses these id's to trigger the modal.

`:id="'exampleModalScrollable'+tree.id"`

`:data-target="'#exampleModalScrollable'+tree.id"`

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ellisdod/bgzqryxm/)

You might want to consider bootstrap-vue which doesnt rely on jQuery and works more directly with Vue.